# How to receive notification of NSTextField textDidEndEditing from C++?

Tags: c++, objective-c, cocoa, qt

I have an Objective-C++ program that uses an NSSearchField. Specifically, the NSSearchField is wrapped in a QMacCocoaViewContainer derivative (Qt). How can I set things up so that I can receive notification of textDidEndEditing from a Qt signal? Will I need a pure Objective-C class that uses NSNotificationCenter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're on iOS4, looks like you can have your notification delivered to a block instead. NSNotificationCenter sports this method:

```
- (id)addObserverForName:(NSString *)name object:(id)obj queue:(NSOperationQueue *)queue usingBlock:(void (^)(NSNotification *))block NS_AVAILABLE(10_6, 4_0);
```

Then you could do something like:

MyClass.m:

```
static void (^receiveNote)(NSNotification *) = ^(NSNotification * note)
{
    UITextField * field = [ note object ] ;
    // forward notification to C++ here
} ;
```

...

```
@implementation MyClass
```

...

```
-(void)setUpNotifications
{
    [ [ NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter ] addObserverForName:UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification 
                                                         object:self.textField 
                                                          queue:[ NSOperationQueue mainQueue ] 
                                                     usingBlock:receiveNote ] ;
}
```

Comment: oh--says it's available on OS X 10.6 too

Comment: Since the NSSearchField is wrapped by a C++ class, how can I get the posted notification to link back up with that specific C++ class instance?

Comment: There's no "clean" way that I know of. How many search fields can you have?If you only have a few search fields, you can just check each search field to see if it's associated NSSearchField is `[ note object ]`.

Comment: Are you starting a new app or is it a legacy app? I don't suppose building with appkit (instead of Qt) is an option? (Not trying to be obnoxious)

Comment: Maintaining an existing app. Way too late to switch to AppKit at this point. ;)

Comment: Accepting your answer since this is 90% of what I needed. Thanks!